# Sort order list view by 'logged in user' in SuiteCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Removing default sort order in list view and sorting by 'Logged in user' in SuiteCRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without customizing the code in include/listView/ListViewDate.php, just add the following code in custom/modules/(your module)/views/view.list.php

```
    function listViewProcess() {

            global $current_user; 
            $user_name = $current_user->user_name;
            $id = $current_user->id;
            $this->processSearchForm();
                $this->params['overrideOrder']='1';
                $this->params['orderBy']='1';
                $this->params['custom_order_by'] = ' ORDER BY FIELD(accounts.assigned_user_id, "'.$id.'") DESC';
                $this->lv->setup($this->seed, 'include/ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl', $this->where, $this->params);
            $savedSearchName = empty($_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']) ? '' : (' - ' . $_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']);
            echo $this->lv->display();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code in custom/modules/Prospects(your module)/views/view.list.php

```
 function listViewProcess() {

    global $current_user; 
    $user_name = $current_user->user_name;
    $id = $current_user->id;
    $this->processSearchForm();

        $this->params['custom_order_by'] = ' ORDER BY FIELD(assigned_user_id, "'.$id.'") DESC';
        $this->lv->setup($this->seed, 'include/ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl', $this->where, $this->params);
        $savedSearchName = empty($_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']) ? '' : (' - ' . $_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']);
        echo $this->lv->display();
}
```

custom_order_by will be considered as second order by field
so declare

`$ret_array['order_by']='';`  in include/ListView/ListViewData.php

before

```
$main_query = $ret_array['select'] . $params['custom_select'] . $ret_array['from'] . $params['custom_from'] . $ret_array['inner_join']. $ret_array['where'] . $params['custom_where'] . $ret_array['order_by'] . $params['custom_order_by'];
```